# Remove statusbar and navigationsbar overlay while displaying dialog

Tags: android, background, tooltip, background-color, statusbar

I am trying to display a Tooltip dialog when the user taps on any view. 
I don't want the overlay to appear on the status bar and navigation bar when the dialog is shown:

```
 dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.ToolTip_background);
```

**I tried**

```
<style name="ToolTip_background" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

**and in java code:**

```
View view=dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        Drawable dim = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        dim.setBounds(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        dim.setAlpha(0);
        ViewGroupOverlay overlay = view.getOverlay();
        overlay.add(dim);
```

nothing worked

**note:** 
If I tried adding `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>`  it works, but the Tooltip anchor position with respect to my view gets shifted to different position on different phones.

Comment: I don't see you setting that theme anywhere.

Comment: @TheWanderer : edited the question